# Turning curl into ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, curl

I have the following curl bash command:

```
curl -d "username=UID&password=PASS" http://localhost:8080
```

I want to translate it into an ajax request in java script. How would I do so?

I have tried the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'username=' + form.username.value + '&password=PASS',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

where form.username.value contains UID, but it does not seem to work. The server does not seem to receive the request.

Comment: Assuming you are making the ajax request from localhost:8080/someform, you need to use a relative path as the url and not a full URI as you have here. If you are just posting to the index page, then just replace your URI with '/'

Comment: if the server file is server.py, then i would put url: '/server.py' ?

Comment: Im making ajax request from a html file, login.html. it is in the same folder with server.py.

Comment: correct, you should change the URL to '/server.py'

Comment: I have tried that and it is not working still

Comment: Are you watching your Javascript console? It will probably give you some information as to why it is failing. If you are getting errors, what are they?

Comment: Im using this:     error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
      console.log(xhr.statusText);
      console.log(textStatus);
    }
and it just prints out 'error', 'error'

Comment: It's hard to tell, if server.py is accessible at `localhost:8080/server.py` and login.html is accessible at `localhost:8080/login.html`, then it should work. If not, it's probably a cross-domain issue with your html file accessible from a server/port that isn't the same server/port your server-side script is accessible from. Javascript won't allow this behavior for security purposes.

Comment: you are probably right. In server.py i have: if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(
            ('localhost', 8080), CustomHandler)
        httpd.serve_forever()
and my html file is started by opening in the browser, file:///Users/user/Desktop/login.html. Any tip on how to make it accessible at localhost:8080/login.html?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        username: form.username.value,
        password: PASS
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: it says PASS is not defined. If i used 'PASS', it doesnt work as before

Answer (score 0):

You might try opening the html file not as `file:///Users/user/Desktop/login.html` but instead set it up so that you're accessing it through the server. I had some JavaScript being blocked for security reasons when I was accessing the page that called it as file, but the problem disappeared when I fired up a server and accessed the page as `http://localhost:8080/...`

Comment: Can you share how you set it up to access the html through the server?

Comment: I just put a symlink to the folder containing my html and js files in the htdocs folder of my server. Or you could copy the files. Specifically, using MAMP as PHP server on my Mac, there is a folder /Appplications/MAMP/htdocs where you put pages to be served up. Inside that folder I put a symlink to my `myapp` folder, fired up the server, and voila: `http://localhost:8888/myapp/index.html` can be opened in my browser and no longer throws the security exception.